# Is there a way to pass the data of a ggplot2 call to the scale_* functions that works with .+gg in one pass

Tags: r, ggplot2, rlang

With ggplot2 in R I would like to take the `data` parameter of a `ggplot` call and somehow use it in a scale_* function if that is possible, in one pass rather than two.

In one of the first examples [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html) you can see that `geom_bar` can access the data with the `.data` pronoun:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::mpg) + 
ggplot2::geom_bar(ggplot2::aes(x = .data$drv))
```

However, if one were to try the same approach with scale_x_continuous:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) +
geom_point() +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(min(.data$displ),  max(.data$displ)))
```

The `.data$displ` doesn't 'find' anything, and the scales return empty:

```
Warning messages:
1: In min(.data$displ) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(.data$displ) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Instead, what one can do is:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) +
geom_point() -> p
p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(min(p$data$displ),  max(p$data$displ)))
```

But I had hoped there would be a way to do this in one pass.

Another approach that I've tried is to use `%$%` from maggritr but this also proved unfruitful, and perhaps overly complicated.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
mpg %$%
ggplot(data.frame(displ,hwy), aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) +
geom_point() +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(min(displ),  max(displ)))
```

```
Error in check_breaks_labels(breaks, labels) : object 'displ' not found
```

Suggesting that the variables `displ` and `hwy` are only passed forward by `%$%` to the first function, but are not available elsewhere.

A more general question and related question, is are ggproto Scale_* objects able to access the 'nearby' data.

Comment: I find this to be very frustrating myself. One approach I have employed in the past is to enclose the entire ggplot call in `{}`. That enables one to access `.` multiple times. IE `mpg %>% {ggplot(., aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) + geom_point() +  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(min(.$displ),  max(.$displ)))}` I agree though, this is a missing feature.

Comment: This isn't too bad, I can probably live with this if there isn't a more resilient solution. Thanks a lot!